# Date formatting to dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: lightning-aura-components, date

My salesforce environment is on right Local setting all data on Salesforce Org is display as 'dd/mm/yyyy'.

Recently I build a Lightning page which display some dates.but they display as 'yyyy-mm-dd'
How can I change it to 'dd/mm/yyyy' this is how it display in Salesforce.
my lightnening component - there are two date fields as Start_date__c and Training_outcome_date__c.

```
<aura:handler name="init" action="{!c.doInit}" value="{!this}" />
<aura:attribute name="agreementRows" type="Training_Agreement__c[]"/> 

<ltng:require styles="/resource/SLDS102/assets/styles/salesforce-lightning-design-system-ltng.css" 
scripts="/resource/Jquery" /> 

<div class="slds">
<p>
    <b>   Completed Trainees  </b>
</p>
<br>
</br>
<table class="slds-table slds-table--bordered slds-max-medium-table--stacked" >
    <thead>
        <tr class ="slds-text-heading--label"> 
            <td class = "boldHeader slds-cell-wrap slds-size--1-of-7">Traineee Name</td>
            <td class = "boldHeader slds-cell-wrap slds-size--1-of-7">Workplace</td>
            <td class = "boldHeader slds-cell-wrap slds-size--1-of-7">Qualification</td>   
            <td class = "boldHeader slds-cell-wrap slds-size--1-of-7">Start Date</td>  
            <td class = "boldHeader slds-cell-wrap slds-size--1-of-7">Completed Date</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <aura:iteration var="cell" items="{!v.agreementRows}">
            <tr>
                <td data-label="Trainee Name"> {!cell.Trainee_Name__c} </td>
                <td data-label="Workplace"> {!cell.Company__c} </td>
                <td data-label="Qualification"> {!cell.Qualification_Name__c} </td>
                <td data-label="Start Date"> {!cell.Start_Date__c} </td>
                <td data-label="Completed Date"> {!cell.Training_Outcome_Date__c} </td>
            </tr>
        </aura:iteration>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way i can think of is using **outputDate**. For ex:

```
<aura:handler name="init" action="{!c.doInit}" value="{!this}" />
<aura:attribute name="agreementRows" type="Training_Agreement__c[]"/> 

<ltng:require styles="/resource/SLDS102/assets/styles/salesforce-lightning-design-system-ltng.css" 
scripts="/resource/Jquery" /> 

<div class="slds">
<p>
    <b>   Completed Trainees  </b>
</p>
<br>
</br>
<table class="slds-table slds-table--bordered slds-max-medium-table--stacked" >
    <thead>
        <tr class ="slds-text-heading--label"> 
            <td class = "boldHeader slds-cell-wrap slds-size--1-of-7">Traineee Name</td>
            <td class = "boldHeader slds-cell-wrap slds-size--1-of-7">Workplace</td>
            <td class = "boldHeader slds-cell-wrap slds-size--1-of-7">Qualification</td>   
            <td class = "boldHeader slds-cell-wrap slds-size--1-of-7">Start Date</td>  
            <td class = "boldHeader slds-cell-wrap slds-size--1-of-7">Completed Date</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <aura:iteration var="cell" items="{!v.agreementRows}">
            <tr>
                <td data-label="Trainee Name"> {!cell.Trainee_Name__c} </td>
                <td data-label="Workplace"> {!cell.Company__c} </td>
                <td data-label="Qualification"> {!cell.Qualification_Name__c} </td>
                <td data-label="Start Date"> 
                <ui:outputDate value="{!cell.Start_Date__c}"/>
                </td>
                <td data-label="Completed Date"> 
                    <ui:outputDate value="{!cell.Training_Outcome_Date__c}"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </aura:iteration>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

For more info: refer https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_ui_outputDate.htm?search_text=ui:outputDate